# How to open from android Java Fragment a Jetpack Compose Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, android-jetpack, composable

I have legacy fragment code, and I need to open from fragment Dialog which is written as composable:

I have such class:

```
class FullScreenDialogActivity
@JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null) :
    AbstractComposeView(context, attrs) {
    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
      Dialog(
          title = "d",
          desc = "",
          onDismiss = {
               dialog.value = false
                     }
          )
}
```

but how can I open such dialog from java fragment class?

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
   //FullScreenDialogActivity()
}
}
```

and this dialog should be on the top of the fragment

Answer (score 0):

You can call it from any fragment method like this:

```
private void yourMethodOrOnClickMethodFromXml() {
        FullScreenDialogActivity dialog = new FullScreenDialogActivity(getContext());
        getActivity().setContentView(dialog);
}
```